# Add array to conditional jQuery show/hide script

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, addition

I am using a jQuery script with PHP to conditionally show/hide form fields based on dropdown selection.
The script is:

```
//Hide the field initially
        $("#hide1").hide();

        //Show the text field only when the third option is chosen - this doesn't
        $('#project-type').change(function() {
                if ($("#project-type").val() == "Value 1") {
                        $("#hide1").show();
                }
                else {
                        $("#hide1").hide();
                }
        });
```

I want to be able to add an array of values to the `if ($("#project-type").val() == "Value 1")` so if there are five values, I want a certain field to show when values 1 and 3 are selected but not the others. I have tried a few methods but they all result in all the values showing the hidden field.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery inArray should do the work;

```
var val = $("#project-type").val(); // Project type value.

var show = $.inArray(val, ['Value 1', 'Value 2', ...]) > -1 ? 'show' : 'hide'; // If the value is in the array, show value is 'show' otherwise it is 'hide'.

$("#hide1")[show](); // Show or hide $('#hide1').
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options, an easy one would be to change your if to:

```
if ($("#project-type").val() == "Value 1" || $("#project-type").val() == "Value 3")
```

or:

```
if (["Value 1", "Value 3"].indexOf($("#project-type").val()) != -1)
```